# Развернуть в phaserJS спрайт зеркально

Tags: javascript, спрайт, phaser-framework

Не могу найти в документации. Как развернуть спрайт зеркально. Т.е. изначально, как он нарисован, двигается вполне нормально. Но нужно его развернуть зеркально, когда он идет в обратную сторону. Я знаю, что в теории можно нарисовать другой спрайт-лист и просто использовать его, но у такого мощного движка как phaser должно быть что-то родное на такой случай.

[Вот пример того как двигается вперед.](http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=animation&f=animation+events.js&t=animation%20events)

Вопрос на знание phaser, как нативно развернуть спрайт зеркально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно просто было сделать масштабирование по x в -1

```
sprite.scale.x = -1;
```